# Registering a Bower package from a private Git repository to a Private Bower host

Tags: javascript, git, bower, packaging

I am working for an enterprise which uses private `Git` repositories and we have a private `Bower` server inside our `VPN` which is caching public packages correctly (our private `Bower` server in a `Docker` cannot access `Git`).

Now, we want to register our own package, but nothing works so far:

```
bower register our-assets git://our-host:6789/our-assets
bower our-assets#*      resolve git://our-host:6789/our-assets#*
bower our-assets#*      ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://our-host:6789/our-assets", exit code of #128 fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /our-assets
```

I also tried the '@' in the URL parameter:

```
bower register our-assets git@our-host:6789/our-assets
bower our-assets#*      resolve git@our-host:6789/our-assets#*
bower our-assets#*      ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git@our-host:6789/our-assets", exit code of #128 Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Bower, Docker, etc, but from reading the output I doubt it really has to do with any of these things. Instead it seems to be purely a Git/network/setup issue.

I’d suggest you remove the layers and focus on the core of the issue, which from the output appears to be that Git is unable to perform a fetch. So try to see if the commands it complains about also fail on their own and, if they do, fix that first:

```
$ git ls-remote --tags --heads git://our-host:6789/our-assets
$ git ls-remote --tags --heads git@our-host:6789/our-assets
```